# Restoring database giving error

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

When I try to restore my database backup, I am getting following error.

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 214; 1259 32064 TABLE country_amd0 userldd
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "userldd" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE country_amd0 OWNER TO userldd;
```

Does anybody know what this error is about?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

A custom-format dump is just of the database its self, not the global state like users.

If you don't have a `pg_dump --globals-only` too, you will need to re-create any:

- roles (users/groups)
- tablespaces

and other global objects referenced by the dump.

It's a shame that `pg_dump` doesn't auto-include those if referenced by the dump, so you could optionally restore them too. A patch for this would be very welcome, but so far nobody's stepped up.